# Question about war

Tags: philosophy-of-war

If we are civilized enough to be able to set rules for war, why can't war be non-lethal? Why not something else competitive? If we still want to be violent, why not just have an MMA match?

Comment: What would force a country to follow through with the terms of the war if they lose? What would happen if one country wants to invade another country but that second country doesn't want to have a war? One country invading another happens all the time, why would the second country agree? Who says that we're civil enough to set rules for war? Every country in the security council of the UN violates international law every year, an example being the US's use of white phosphorus tipped missiles in Syria. People are not perfectly rational, nobody would agree to this idea and stick with it.

Comment: You're delusional if you think that there are countries in the world whose government would agree to sign a treaty that all future conflicts will be resolved by an MMA match. Whatever your point is about climate change is a non sequitur

Comment: Limiting war and making war non lethal are two different things, the question asks about making wear nonlethal

Comment: Sadly the event of war requires the proper narrative heft to make it satisfying for the species. We see this also in the mystery novel. It is extremely rare to find a mystery novel that does not involve a murder.

Comment: Civil, as in civilian, is distinct from military, as in war. So instead of "civilized enough" maybe "empathetic" enough is a more sound question?

Comment: Very similar scenario actually happened between GB and India. Gandhi basically drove out the Brits by just throwing a tantrum. You can only do that to a very civilized nation. In hindsight, that peaceful surrender turned out to be the most stupidest thing the British have ever done - it was crime in view of the misery that followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We aren't civilized enough to set rules about war, we are only civilized enough to punish behaviors that we find repugnant, afterward.  We would like to believe that we have control over the behavior of human beings at their worst.  But obviously, U.S. soldiers in our very most recent war committed severe breaches of the supposed rules of war, e.g. at [Abu Ghraib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Ghraib_torture_and_prisoner_abuse), for which we then had to make reparations.  And those were not even soldiers in combat, making unfortunate decisions due to unbearable pressure.  They were just bored prison guards.

Being able to set accounts into balance after the fact is not the same as having actual control.  The Salic code of [weregeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weregild) did not end revenge killing centuries and centuries ago.  It made it unprofitable for the clans that did it.  But that did not stop anything.  Killing for revenge still goes on, not just in France, but everywhere.

Rulers do not really have control over their subjects -- no human being really has control over another human being.  We like to think that we have established control over the emotional excesses of our fellow human beings, but this is only a rationalization.

So obviously, if we chose to replace war with something else, real war would happen in an unsanctioned manner anyway, and we would end up having hypocritical clean-up mechanisms that then 'undid' it.  Given the dramatic cost of modern war, and the fact that we still engage in it anyway, it is not clear that an additional 'wrapper' mechanism that made it even more inefficient, would do anything productive at all.

Comment: this won't be helpful, but i don't understand your lead sentence.

Comment: @user3293056  There isn't a lot of evidence that we can actually make people who are engaged in war actually follow the rules.  There have always been supposed rules and limits to war, all the way back to Homeric Greece.  And the degree to which people obey them does not seem to have changed.  (Except to the degree we select those people more carefully beforehand.)  So people immersed in war are no more civilized about it while it is going on than we ever were, even though we now have the idea of war crimes, and accountability to an international law.

Comment: no i get what you mean, i'm just being weird about how you said it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

In Georges Bataille's book called Eroticism, he talks about transgression of taboo as a signifier of what is sacred in a culture - a taboo is not absolute, a taboo is meant to delimit the world of work - so a taboo on war is a taboo on death, and violence in general. But the taboo on war is not absolute, and in war there is an element of showing what is sacred to that culture.

I think your understanding could be something like "the function of war is to negotiate conflict" - whereas Bataille's understanding could be something like "the taboo on war exists because of the taboo on death, and violence in particular, which is not an absolute taboo (which would mean it was never permitted) but rather a taboo that can be seen as relative to the needs of organising society for work, and signifying what is sacred for members of that society".

Sometimes it is the violation of a principle that is sacred to a community which is the spark for violent conflict.

I think what seems to be your idea of war as a system of negotiating conflict that is not necessarily violent does not take into account a deeper idea about the function of war in the development of human culture.

I think ideas about the necessity of war as *necessarily violent* conflict is tied up with the development of human culture, according to the delimitation of the profane and sacred worlds through the observance of taboos that are not absolute but rather relative to the need for work.

Answer (score 1):

We already have such a rule. The Hague Convention, Article 1 states

> "the Contracting Powers agree to use their best efforts to ensure the pacific settlement of international differences."

Therefore if either side thought it were possible to resolve the dispute by an MMA match, or any other less violent means than war, they are already bound by international treaty to do so.

This leaves us with the conclusion either that all international powers are breaking their treaties and having wars which could be resolved some other way (in which case they would ignore your proposed rule equally), or they consider there to be something about the nature of the dispute which actually requires the killing of their opponent's soldiers.